# Regex to include the string values not substring values

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

> name:ABC;
>
> username:XYZ;

I want to remove the name value `ABC` from the string, so I am using the following regex:

```
((?<=name))(.*?)(?=;)
```

It successfully selects the `name` value, but the problem is it also selects the `username` value.

I want to remove only the `name` values not `username` values.
How can I do that?

**SOLUTION**:

**Both `Avinash` and `Bohemian` answer's are correct for this question.
By `Avinash` answer we can exclude all the words contains `name` as substring and with `Bohemian` answer we can exclude specific words.

Comment: If you provide more context where these strings appear, a solution could be different and much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` before `name`.

```
(?<=\bname:)(.*?)(?=;)
```

or

```
(?<=\bname:)[^;]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your regex, you can combine two look behinds, one positive, one negative:

```
(?<!username)(?<=name).*?(?=;)
```

Note also the removal of unnecessary brackets.

Avinash's answer is probably what I would use in this case, but I thought I would show this way in case `\b` didn't work for future visitors, eg all data whose name ends in `name` (`streetname`, `cityname`, etc) *except* `username`.